# Draw on surface - unexpected behaviour

Tags: annotation

I am using v3.5 official release. Whenever I try adding an annotation with placement on *Surface* while in *Top/Bottom/Side View* to an object, the result is that the annotation appears to intersect with the gridlines. The reason I think this is that I can turn off the viewport overlays and draw annotations on the same object, also in side view, and then with the overlays re-enabled, the annotation mostly adheres to the surface of the object, but is still jagged and not placed on the surface precisely. The behaviour doesn't appear when I am annotating on a mesh in perspective view. In perspective view, the behaviour disappears entirely, and I get a perfectly smooth line drawn across the mesh.

The behaviour is likely caused by something I have saved as a setting in my startup file, but I don't know what setting it could be. The reason I think this is because I have another file using the same technique that I made in Jan 2022, and I can still open that one and draw on it in side view just fine, and when I open a fresh instance of Blender and choose another of the default startup files (i.e. VFX, Sculpting, Video Editing), the behaviour is nonexistent.

I used annotations to demonstrate the problem, but the behaviour also exists with the draw tool within the edit mode of a curve object, for example.

This is a screenshot from my most recent file, where the unexpected behaviour is seen:

[image]

The annotations that jut out were made with viewport overlays ON, while the annotations that appear on the surface of the mesh were made with viewport overlays OFF.

Here is a screenshot of the old file where the technique still works fine:

[image]

Here is a screenshot with some colour-coded annotations to hopefully make the issue more clear:

[image]

Like I said, I am almost certain it's a setting that I changed somewhere, but I have no idea where to even begin looking because the behaviour appears to be related to the overlays, and I tried playing with those settings and didn't get anywhere. I've attached my file so it can be investigated:

[image]

Comment: I upgraded to 3.6 and the issue was resolved[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVAKi.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVAKi.png)